# in c# Console application what will be the logic regarding this issue?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to practice file handling.

This is what I want to do:

1. Read data from a file
2. Delete some lines from the file, for example from line 10 to line 19, which I will decide at the console.

I have finished the first part, but I don't know how to do the second part. I'm new to programming, so I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace prac
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader rw = new StreamReader("read.txt");
            string line = "";
            while (line != null) 
            {
                line = rw.ReadLine();
                if (line !=null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }

            }
            rw.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to read the file after that user can edit and update file in run time im stuck in this part bro :)

Comment: You're going to have a hard time updating the file (and re-saving it) in the console. Sure, it can be done, but probably not in any way you're expecting.

Comment: You should try a WinForm or WPF project instead of a console app.

Comment: @JacobRoberts How will that help?

Comment: @DStanley I think Jacob is suggesting that Mirza should load the file into a textarea, edit it there, and hit a save button to save it back out to disk. like notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a full app

```
private static void Main()
        {
            // Read all the lines
            List<string> currentFileLines = File.ReadAllLines("read.txt").ToList();

            // Ask the user the line to start from
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the line you wish to delete from:");

            // Ask the user for start line
            int starLine = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Ask the user the line to
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the line you wish to delete to:");

            // Ask the user for end line
            int endLine = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Remove the lines
            currentFileLines.RemoveRange(starLine - 1, endLine - (starLine - 1));

            // Save the file
            File.WriteAllLines("read.txt", currentFileLines);

            // Show the line on the screen
            foreach (string line in currentFileLines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: This assumes the file you read will not be that large as its all read into memory also no error checking.

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish what you're wanting

```
        // Read the entire file
        List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();
        fileLines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("read.txt"));

        // Indexes start at 0. 9 actually represent line 10, 
        // and the 10 means to remove 10 items from the list
        fileLines.RemoveRange(9, 10); // This is actually line 10

        // Write the entire file back out now that it has been modified
        File.WriteAllLines("read.txt", fileLines);
```

If you would like to remove "given" lines from the file, you can ask the user for input, as to which line to start the removal process and how many lines to remove.  Take these two numbers and just replace the 9 & 10 in the RemoveRange( ) sample that I've provided.

Comment: I think OP wants to remove lines 10 *through* 19.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. You said you would determine "at the console" which lines you want to keep or delete, so that's what I've implemented below.

Basically it just writes each line out to the console and asks the user if they want to delete it. If they press 'K', then the line is kept, and is added to a `List<string>` internally. If they press 'D' (to delete), then the line is not added to the list.

They also have the option to press 'C' (for cancel), in which case nothing is done to the file, or 'S' (for save), in which case any lines they've marked for deletion are removed and they don't have to sit through the rest of the file.

```
public static void ReadWriteFile(string filePath)
{
    if (filePath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException("filePath");

    var newLines = new List<string>();
    bool cancelled = false;
    bool promptForInput = true;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        int lineNumber = 0;
        string currentLine;

        while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (promptForInput)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("#{0}: {1}", ++lineNumber, currentLine);
                Console.Write("[K]eep or [D]elete this line, [S]ave changes, " + 
                    "or [C]ancel (default = 'K'): ");

                var input = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.D)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Marked line #{0} for deletion", lineNumber);
                    continue;
                }
                if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancelling operation. No changes saved.");
                    cancelled = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
                {
                    promptForInput = false;
                }
            }

            newLines.Add(currentLine);
        }
    }

    if (!cancelled)
    {
        // By overwriting with the saved lines, we effectively delete the other lines
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting selected lines from file...");
        File.WriteAllLines(filePath, newLines);
    }
}
```

Comment: somehow this code is helping me for my practice problem thanks buddy !